# how to change this recursive to loop

Tags: python

I want to write all base-26 numbers (with letters of the alphabet as digits) of a certain length into an ASCII-file.
For length = 4 this would look like

```
aaaa
aaab
aaac
...
zzzx
zzzy
zzzz
```

I achieved this with the following recursive code:

```
def fuz(data, ll_str):
    ll_str += 1
    def for_once(data_once, ll_str_once):
        tmp_str = ll_str_once
        tmp_str -= 1
        new_data = []
        for m in data_once:
            for i1 in range(97, 123):
                new_data.append(m + chr(i1))
        if tmp_str != 0:
            return for_once(new_data, tmp_str)
        else:
            return data_once
    return for_once(data, ll_str)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ll = 4
    test = ['']
    file_output = open("out.txt", 'a')
    out_data = fuz(test, ll)
    for out in out_data:
        file_output.write(out + '\n')
    file_output.close()
```

However, for any length > 4, this solution runs out of memory on my machine.

Therefore I look for an alternative without recursion - can anybody give me a hint how to do this?

Comment: what does your code do?

Comment: Used to generate a string of any length with 26 letters

Answer (score 0):

This loop writes all base-26 numbers of length 4 (with letters as digits) in a file named out.txt.
base and length can be arbitrarily chosen - but prepare to be patient for higher values...

```
import itertools as it

base = 26
lngth = 4
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    for t in it.product(range(97, 97+base), repeat=lngth):
        s = ''.join(map(chr, (t)))
        f.write(s + chr(13))
```

At least it doesn't consume too much memory, as requested by the OP.
However, with base 26 a length 5 file had already 70MB and a length 6 file I stopped the writing process at 1.4GB; there Notepad++ was already not able to open it anymore. So everybody can think about the use of this code by himself.